# Getting block data from YQL

Tags: yql, yahoo-finance

I read up on YQL. However i'm at a loss on how to get blocks of data.

I can get individual stock data fine but how do you get collated data like the FTSE 100 shares, without having to find the symbol for each 100 shares and pulling that data in individually?

Ideally i would have the hundred shares with each of their bits of data.

Thanks in advance,
Ewan

Answer (score 1):

looks like you are right that only one stock can be queried at a time. since the api is restful, you can easily use a for loop in bash and curl all the stocks.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we query YQL table we need to give the SYMBOLS (tickers) as inputs. However there is a limit to the number of symbols you can enter in one go.

I created an Excel sheet where I read a list of symbols from a sheet and then query with YQL and dump the data in another sheet.

Let's assume you want to pull out historical prices with the following specifications:

- Symbol/Ticker : symbol
- StartDate
- EndDate

The corresponding weblink to extract this info would be (in VBA syntax)

```
"http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.historicaldata%20where%20symbol%20in%20%28%27 " & symbol & "%27%29%20and%20startDate%20=%20%27" & startDate & "%27%20and%20endDate%20=%20%27" & endDate & "%27&diagnostics=true&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys"
```

You can find the Excel sheet present at [my blog](http://simplyanant.blogspot.in/2015/03/pulling-stock-data-through-ryql.html).